# why aren't the entries deleting even if the condition meets in the where clause?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, cron

I got this code on the console Kernel.php file within the schedule function:

```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        User::where('deleted_at', '<=', Carbon::now())->delete();
    })->everyMinute();
```

It should delete all the users that have passed the deleted_at time variable, I launch the cron job in my local server with the command `php artisan schedule:work` since I have no server yet. The code executes every minute but nothing happens and there is no error. I tried with the simple now() but still nothing, I tried maybe setting the local time instead of the default UTC but also nothing

Comment: Is your User model using soft deletes? Often a column of `deleted_at` is associated with the model having `use SoftDeletes;`. If that's the case, you need to use `->forceDelete()` instead of `->delete()`

Comment: yes, I do use SoftDeletes, I will try this first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Soft deleted models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models) do not show up with a regular Eloquent query, you need to use the `withTrashed()` or `onlyTrashed()` methods. If you're looking to permanently delete all the soft-deleted users, I'd suggest something like this, using [the `forceDelete()` method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#permanently-deleting-models):

```php
$schedule->call(fn() => User::onlyTrashed()->forceDelete())->everyMinute();
```

Comment: I replaced the delete with the forcedelete and it worked, thanks!

Comment: No problem. There's no point in checking timestamps for soft-deleted models. The `deleted_at` column will either be null or not; that's what `onlyTrashed()` is checking for.

Comment: thanks! I understand better how softDeletes works now